# For loop PLSQL Statement Ignored

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

```
create or replace procedure salarycompall as 

CURSOR empIDs IS SELECT employee_id from EMPLOYEES;

begin
  
  FOR e in empIDs
    LOOP
        SALARYCOMP(e);
    END LOOP;
    
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
end salarycompall;
```

This procedure should call another procedure SALARYCOMP. The SALARYCOMP expects the Datatype EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%type, but i get the errors Error(7,9): PL/SQL: Statement ignored and Error(7,9): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SALARYCOMP'.

I have tried just printing out every e in empIDs but i get the same errors, so is there something wrong in my for loop?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cursor loop variable `e` is a record, not a scalar value; you need to refer to the field within that record:

```
SALARYCOMP(e.employee_id);
```

---

To think about why you can't just pass `e`, imagine your cursor query was:

```
SELECT employee_id, manager_id from EMPLOYEES
```

Then if you called `SALARYCOMP(e)` you wouldn't just be passing the `employee_id` it's expecting, you'd be passing both `employee_id` and `manager_id`; so then it's more obvious that're you're passing a record comprised of both values, and that you actually need to specify the field you meant, with `SALARYCOMP(e.employee_id`).

With only one column in your cursor query it's perhaps a bit less obvious - but it's still the same mechanism, and isn't treated any differently. Calling `SALARYCOMP(e)` still passes the whole record (with a single field).